# How to restrict my screen share only to Virtual Machine Desktop and do not show Host desktop?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, virtual-desktop

In an interview where screen share is must. I have few code things on my Windows 7 laptop (Host).
Sometimes I would use few copy paste which I don't want to be seen.

So I want to

```
 -- > open another Windows7 (Virtual Machine) which I already have. 
 -- > within VM, open a browser and the connect  meeting
 -- > a) share the VM desktop only 
      b) but don't show the Host desktop to interviewer
      c) I should be visible thru my LapTop WebCam either from VM or from Host
```

[image]
Is that possible ? What would be the steps ? [ I prefer free wares only. ]

---

### BEWARE : Update after I tested and works perfect ::

One can clearly understood when you switch between *guest_Desktop* vs *Host_Desktop* bcoz of the *Mouse pointer*.

Rather I would prefer a freewares :

```
a. that can create 2 screen split Window and allows to share one of them
b. use a software like eithermouse.com and have two USB Mouse connected to Laptop (1 mouse installed in each Screen).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start anything from the virtual machine itself, such as a screen meeting, teamviewer, etc... the viewer can only see anything inside the VM. They will not even know they are inside a VM until you start copying stuff in from outside. Technically they still don't know, but they can make an educated guess if they are experienced enough.

All you need to do is ensure that you get your webcam connected to the VM and install its drivers there, so it works entirely inside the VM. This can be achieved by enabling USB pass through and select your webcam from the menu, so it shows up in your VM.

EDIT to answer comment:

> thanks...example of educated guess ?

Lets say you show the desktop to someone else. You move the mouse to the far right of the screen (they can see the mousepointer move), you go to an off-screen document to copy/paste some text, you move back to the VM, and paste the text in a document there. Out of nowhere, text appears. Someone who knows VM's exists will know that text cannot appear out of nowhere, so it must have come from somewhere. So either you remote into this pc yourself, or it runs inside a VM.

> How to create USB pass through ?

At the top in your window, there is a menu that says USB. My Virtualbox is dutch, so the menu may be named differently on your end. It should be Devices -> USB -> Click on the device you want to pass through.

Do note, for USB Passthrough to work, the webcam has to work in your host too without using VirtualBox.

> And do I need bridge adapter instead of NAT for anything ?

Bridging vs NAT is only for your network connection. If you set it to bridge, you place the VM in its entirely in your network. This can be very helpful if the meeting software does not work. With NAT it creates a virtual network where you may have to open ports through VirtualBox in order to allow access from outside. Usually with websites, NAT is fine, but this is one of those cases, if you can test it prior to the meeting, test and see what it does. Bridge mode is always going to work, so it is up to you if you want this machine to be in your private network, or that you want to shield it.

> And anything for promicious mode Allow all or default

Unfortunately, I don't undertand this last question. Google gave me this though https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=44258

Comment: thanks...example of educated guess ? How to create USB pass through ? And do I need bridge adapter instead of NAT for anything ? And anything  for promicious mode Allow all or default?

Comment: I made an edit to address your questions

Comment: Awesome !...and many many thanks...will give it a try...accepting as answer hoping for minor asks you will help again :)

Comment: Any idea to hide mouse and key board events? Something is there like "mose pointer integration" "Auto Keyboard capture"

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If i switch between host and guest, with there be any pop up like "Rgt+Cntrl pressed".."you r mouse is swtiched to VM now"...etc etc...if so i need to supress...any idea?

Comment: These popup's show up only on the host, not the guest. In order to make this invisible, you just release and you can set in the options to never show this popup, but again, this is not visible to the guest anyway.

Comment: @ArnabDutta; Just beware of using audio through a VM. Often noise-cancelling doesn’t work and you’ll get feedback/echo if you’re in a meeting.

Comment: I installed BlueJeans within my guest OS and tested a meeting with HeadPhone. 
All worked perfect. I'm using VirtualBox 6.1 and I did one option : 
   Open VM Manager --> RgtClick <<guestVM >> --> Settings --> Audio :: 
          a. Check Enable Audio Output ...but 
          b. UNCHECK Enable Audio Input 
OR 
   While VM is running within another Window which have Menu items like:
               File | Machine | View | Input | Devices, there check out:
                           Devices  --> Audio
For above I think GuestAddition was already there for me +

Answer (score 0):

You can make your VM full screen in virtual box using Guest Additions. First assign a resonable amount of video memory (about 128 MB is perfect) to VM. Now we will insert the guest additions ISO to the VM CD rom. In the VM window, go to Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD image to insert the ISO disk into the virtual CD drive of the VM. In guest VM windows explorer open the virtual CD drive and run VBoxWindowsAdditions-amd64.exe or VBoxWindowsAdditions-x86.exe depending on your architecture to install the guest additions. After installing reboot the VM. Once VirtualBox Guest Additions are installed, you can see a different resolution settings in the Windows guest desktop control panel settings window and In the VM Window menu, go to View and make sure that the Auto-resize Guest Display option is enabled. Move the mouse pointer over the corner of the VM window, push the left mouse button and change the size of the VM window. (As you change size of other normal windoslws) The resolution of the of guest Windows is automatically changed and you can share screen now.

Comment: I will not vote you down, but this is not the route to go.

Comment: Why @LPChip, I used this way recently

Comment: See my answer. Your answer is more like a workaround. If things go wrong, his desktop gets exposed, but he has all the tools to do it the way he intends to do it, right there.

Comment: wondering then how and where its different from @LPChip answer?

Comment: @arnabdutta this will full screen your VM and it is a workaround

Comment: @ArnabDutta to add to this explaination: because the VM runs full-screen, the moment you switch out of the VM to your host, if the meeting is still on-going, they will see your host. So during the meeting you are restricted to your VM and if by accident you switch to your host, they will see it. They may also by accident press a button that changes your settings so the host becomes visible.